# ruby Regular Expression for HH:MM

Tags: ruby, regex

I need a regular expression that will only match times in HH:MM format but not where a time without HH is given such as:  '4:00' .   It should accept times like 01:00, 23:59, 00:45 but not times such as 4:00, 29:00 etc.  I've found regex that accepts HH:MM and H:MM but I need one to match HH:MM only.

Basically, times like '4:00' shouldnt match,  times like '04:00' should!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: this is what you are looking for `[0-2][0-4]:[0-5][0-9]`. See this demo https://regex101.com/r/wC3oQ3/1

Comment: This however doesn't accept any times after 04:00 until you get to 1#:##.  Such as, 05:00 won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying @james jelo4kul's answer slightly, I think the following is a correct regular expression to meet your requirements:

```
([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):[0-5][0-9]
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I changed it a bit to disallow 24:## but exactly what I needed aside from that!  Thanks.

Comment: Yes thanks, I corrected my code. (sorry for the late comment, I thought I had commented earlier).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a regex:

```
require 'time'

def get_time(str)
  b = str.each_char.each_cons(5).find { |a| ['0', '1', '2'].include?(a.first) &&
    (DateTime.strptime(a.join, '%H:%M') rescue nil) }
  b ? b.join : b
end

get_time "It's 6:07!"  #=> nil
get_time "It's 06:07!" #=> "06:07" 
get_time "It's 23:07!" #=> "23:07" 
get_time "It's 23:77!" #=> nil
```